# How to transfer password using an API

Tags: c#, php, rest, api, encryption

I am developing a REST API (PHP/MySQL), and I want to use this API from my game (Unity/C#). I know how to do the stuff from both side but I'm facing a problem: how to deal with passwords ?

What I think is to use this route to check if a user is valid: `https://my-website.com/api/users/{email}/{password}`
(if this is bad, tell me how to send those values)

Then, I would like to hash the password directly after the input (on the game in C# = I know how to do it), but can I safely send the hash to the server ? Do I store the hash ? And obviously, the check is done on the server side so checking hash against db hash makes the call vulnerable right ? If someone reads the hash during the request, he gets the hash so he can steal info...

I'm lost about all of this actually. And FYI, I'm using HTTPS (so it should avoid man in the middle...).

So the real question is: how to transfer the password securely from the game to the server ?

Comment: Send the credentials in a POST request.

Comment: You should use Post endpoint. You have the same use case as user enters credentials in browser and submits to server for validation.

Comment: Use POST with HTTPS. You don't need to hash it client side, but hash it before storing in the DB.

Comment: You don't check hash against each other. They would be different 99% of the times. You send the plain text in POST request to your server and use the `password_hash()` function by supplying the user password and making the function check against hash stored in the DB. You can send passwords in plain text safely as your connection is HTTPS.

Comment: @vivek_23 _"You don't check hash against each other. They would be different 99% of the times."_ - what?

Comment: The thing is: this has to be a GET request. Or I misunderstand. For me, POST is to add data to DB, not to GET data.. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @CodeCaster I meant something like [this](https://3v4l.org/holVW). The hash generated for `some text` is different each time. And sorry for a big typo there, I meant `passowrd_verify()` instead of `password_hash()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw that your service is an https service, so you can send the username (email) and the password as basic authentication header.
[Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: Ok thanks.. I didn't know that using SSL was that powerful ^^

Comment: Basic acces auth is not part of SSL. But secure protocol makes middle man not able to read content of it.

Comment: Yes, that´s correct.

Comment: Can you explain that further? What's the connection between HTTPS and that authentication? And how to do that effectively? What makes you think that HTTPS alone provides security?

Comment: What i wanted to say is that i would not use basic authentication without https

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to hash the password. By analogy, if you submit a form on a website, it will send the password directly to the server, the web app doesn't need to do anything with it.

Just make sure it's sent over a secure connection. If possible, use [strict transport security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) so there's not even a possibility of sending it in plain text.

Typically, the server will return a cookie or token, after client posts a correct user/password pair, which should then be stored on the client and used to make subsequent calls. This depends on your server-side framework, which must authenticate against that cookie/token in future. By doing so, you don't need to store the password on the client, which is the main security concern.

Comment: Thanks for those details ! :)